# Duplicate entry for key

Tags: java, jpa

I have a simple entity class MappingBean

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints =@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "number" }))
public class MappingBean {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int    mappingid;
private String number;
private String name;

...}
```

When I call

```
entityManager.merge(this.mapping);
```

on a MappingBean instance I sometimes get

```
2015-04-22 16:32:08,552 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-15) Duplicate entry '03054445441' for key 'number'
2015-04-22 16:32:08,568 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (default task-15) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

What may be the cause this exception?

Best regards.

Edmond

Comment: Can you please add the exception stack trace

Comment: `merge` is doing a `insert` or `update`, depending on weather it is a new or existing entity. Obviously, when you get that exception entity manager treats that entity as new while you expect it to treat it as existing. You need some debugging to do, as we don't know how you are calling `merge` and where does `this.mapping` come from.

Comment: In fact I'm getting the exception mostly on new entity.

Comment: Well, are you reusing the values for `number`? The exception is caused by `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "number" })`

Comment: Hi Predag, what do you mean by reusing?

Comment: I mean setting already existing value of `number` to new entity. The exception in your question says you are setting `03054445441` on new entity, while there already is `03054445441` in the database.

Comment: it is very surprising. Even when I empty the database and try to insert (with merge()) a new entity, the exception keeps coming up.

Comment: That's strange. Can you print out the generated SQL, to check if there are two insert statements generated for one entity? Does `MappingBean` have a reference to itself?

Comment: Here is the Hibernate SQL: `Hibernate: insert into MappingBean (number, name) values (?, ?)` and `MappingBean` does not have a reference to itself.

Comment: I don't see how this can fail on empty database. Please double check your setup, and is the empty database really the one used for the test.

Comment: My bad. The number was assigned to another customer and as I was looking for MappingBean by customerid, I could not find any existing Bean with that number for the customer in test. With empty database I did mean that the select query did return no row for that particular customer. I think I just needed som break to approach the issue with some fresh mind. Thanks for the support.

Comment: One of those situations where a new pair of eyes comes useful :) Glad you resolved it.